# TPageControl get index

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe2, tpagecontrol

How do I get the number of the page where there is an object? For example: there is a Button1 on the first page and Button2 on the second page, how do I get the number of the page where there is the Button1 without ActivePageIndex? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's very common to want to find the closest parent of a specific class. So, it pays dividends to make a function to do just that.

```
function GetParentWithClass(Control: TControl; 
  ClassType: TWinControlClass): TWinControl;
begin
  Result := Control.Parent;
  while Assigned(Result) and not (Result is ClassType) do
    Result := Result.Parent;
end;
```

Once you have this in place you can use it to solve your current problem.

```
var
  PageIndex: Integer;
  TabSheet: TTabSheet;
.....
TabSheet := GetParentWithClass(Control, TTabSheet) as TTabSheet;
PageIndex := TabSheet.PageIndex;
```

Having separated the concerns like this you can make use of `GetParentWithClass` in other settings.

Answer (score 2):

```
Function GetPageIndexOfControl(c:TControl):Integer;
begin
   Result := -1;
   While Assigned(c.Parent) and not (c is TTabsheet) do c := c.Parent;
   if Assigned(c) then
     if c is TTabsheet then
       Result := TTabsheet(c).PageIndex;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Showmessage(IntToStr(GetPageIndexOfControl(Button1)));    
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Button1.Parent is TTabSheet then
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(TTabSheet(Button1.Parent).PageIndex));
end;
```

It works if the button is directly in the tab sheet (no panels or other controls). If you have panels, you can walk the parent chain to see if a parent is a TTabSheet:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Ctrl: TWinControl;
begin
  Ctrl := Button1.Parent;
  while Assigned(Ctrl) do
  begin
    if Ctrl is TTabSheet then
    begin
      ShowMessage(IntToStr(TTabSheet(Ctrl).PageIndex));
      Break;
    end
    else
      Ctrl := Ctrl.Parent;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to use `Generics` to avoid repeating

```
PageIndex := TComponentUtil.GetParent<TTabSheet>( MyControl ).PageIndex;
```

with such a class

```
unit ComponentUtils;

interface

uses
  Classes, Controls;

type
  TComponentUtil = class abstract
    class function GetOwner<T : TComponent>( AComponent : TComponent ) : T;
    class function GetParent<T : TWinControl>( AControl : TControl ) : T;
  end;

implementation

{ TComponentUtil }

class function TComponentUtil.GetOwner<T>( AComponent : TComponent ) : T;
var
  LOwner : TComponent;
begin
  LOwner := AComponent.Owner;

  while Assigned( LOwner ) and not ( LOwner is T ) do
    LOwner := LOwner.Owner;

  Result := T( LOwner );
end;

class function TComponentUtil.GetParent<T>( AControl : TControl ) : T;
var
  LParent : TWinControl;
begin
  LParent := AControl.Parent;

  while Assigned( LParent ) and not ( LParent is T ) do
    LParent := LParent.Parent;

  Result := T( LParent );
end;

end.
```

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ;o) the basic was up to you, i just tuned the painting :o)

Comment: Put them in a class helper and it can be even cleaner at the call site!

Answer (score 1):

As far the addition shown here was not asked, I'll add is an other answer

```
Function GetPageIndexOfControl(c:TControl;var PageControl:TPageControl):Integer;
begin
   Result := -1;
   While Assigned(c.Parent) and not (c is TTabsheet) do c := c.Parent;
   if Assigned(c) then
     if c is TTabsheet then
       begin
         Result := TTabsheet(c).PageIndex;
         PageControl := TTabsheet(c).PageControl;
       end;
end;
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  pc:TPageControl;
  i:Integer;
begin
 I := GetPageIndexOfControl(Button1,PC);
 if (i>-1) and Assigned(PC) then
    begin
      PC.ActivePageIndex := i;
      if Assigned(PC.OnChange) then PC.OnChange(PC);
    end;
end;
```